# objectClass: value #3 invalid per syntax

Tags: ldap, openldap

I tried to add a user / principal under the domain created so can proceed with further Java testing, so I created `add_user.ldif` from this [tutorial](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/82544/how-to-create-ad-principal-accounts-using-openldap.html)

```
dn: cn=exuser,cn=ldapadmin,dc=myapp,dc=local
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
distinguishedName: cn=exuser,cn=ldapadmin,dc=myapp,dc=local
cn: exuser
userAccountControl: 514
accountExpires: 0
userPrincipalName: exuser@ldapadmin.myapp.local
servicePrincipalName: exuser

dn: cn=exuser,cn=ldapadmin,dc=myapp,dc=local
changetype: modify
replace: unicodePwd
unicodePwd::IgBUAHCAbwCmAHQAMQAxWiUAIgA=

dn: cn=exuser,cn=ldapadmin,dc=myapp,dc=local
changetype: modify
replace: userAccountControl
userAccountControl: 66048
```

The goal is to create a user under component `exuser` (not yet created) with a password so user can access all the sub elements under the component.

Then I run the `ldapadd` command,

```
sudo ldapadd -x -D cn=ldapadm,dc=myapp,dc=local -w secret -f add_user.ldif
```

it met following error

```
adding new entry "cn=exuser,cn=ldapadmin,dc=myapp,dc=local"
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
    additional info: objectClass: value #3 invalid per syntax
```

is it possible that `user` objectClass can't defined under `cn`? How to fix the issue so I can add this user and is this the correct way to define `principal`?

Answer (score 0):

The `user` object class doesn't exist in the schema, so it can't be created at all, let alone in that subtree. Just remove it, or add it to the schema. You need to create the subtree first.